# В Dimox Breadcrumbs не работает ссылка на родительскую страницу. WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

Вот страница "Услуги" в админ панеле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для выбора записей использую плагин ACF.
Вот сама страница услуг
https://agrochem.su/uslugi/

Вот страница записи, то есть одной из услуг
https://agrochem.su/uslugi/fumigacziya/

Когда нахожусь на странице услуги, при клике на ссылку "Услуги" в хлебных крошках нет перехода на страницу "Услуги". Использую Dimox Breadcrumbs. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Внизу привожу скрипт хлебных крошек из functions.php

```
function dimox_breadcrumbs() {

    /* === ОПЦИИ === */
    $text['home']     = 'Главная'; // текст ссылки "Главная"
    $text['category'] = '%s'; // текст для страницы рубрики
    $text['search']   = 'Результаты поиска по запросу "%s"'; // текст для страницы с результатами поиска
    $text['tag']      = 'Записи с тегом "%s"'; // текст для страницы тега
    $text['author']   = 'Статьи автора %s'; // текст для страницы автора
    $text['404']      = 'Ошибка 404'; // текст для страницы 404
    $text['page']     = 'Страница %s'; // текст 'Страница N'
    $text['cpage']    = 'Страница комментариев %s'; // текст 'Страница комментариев N'

    $wrap_before    = '<div class="breadcrumbs" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">'; // открывающий тег обертки
    $wrap_after     = '</div><!-- .breadcrumbs -->'; // закрывающий тег обертки
    $sep            = '<span class="breadcrumbs__separator"> / </span>'; // разделитель между "крошками"
    $before         = '<span class="breadcrumbs__current">'; // тег перед текущей "крошкой"
    $after          = '</span>'; // тег после текущей "крошки"

    $show_on_home   = 0; // 1 - показывать "хлебные крошки" на главной странице, 0 - не показывать
    $show_home_link = 1; // 1 - показывать ссылку "Главная", 0 - не показывать
    $show_current   = 1; // 1 - показывать название текущей страницы, 0 - не показывать
    $show_last_sep  = 1; // 1 - показывать последний разделитель, когда название текущей страницы не отображается, 0 - не показывать
    /* === КОНЕЦ ОПЦИЙ === */

    global $post;
    $home_url       = home_url('/');
    $link           = '<span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">';
    $link          .= '<a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="%1$s" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">%2$s</span></a>';
    $link          .= '<meta itemprop="position" content="%3$s" />';
    $link          .= '</span>';
    $parent_id      = ( $post ) ? $post->post_parent : '';
    $home_link      = sprintf( $link, $home_url, $text['home'], 1 );

    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {

        if ( $show_on_home ) echo $wrap_before . $home_link . $wrap_after;

    } else {

        $position = 0;

        echo $wrap_before;

        if ( $show_home_link ) {
            $position += 1;
            echo $home_link;
        }

        if ( is_category() ) {
            $parents = get_ancestors( get_query_var('cat'), 'category' );
            foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $cat ) {
                $position += 1;
                if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
                echo sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
            }
            if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                $position += 1;
                $cat = get_query_var('cat');
                echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
                echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
            } else {
                if ( $show_current ) {
                    if ( $position >= 1 ) echo $sep;
                    echo $before . sprintf( $text['category'], single_cat_title( '', false ) ) . $after;
                } elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
            }

        } elseif ( is_search() ) {
            if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                $position += 1;
                if ( $show_home_link ) echo $sep;
                echo sprintf( $link, $home_url . '?s=' . get_search_query(), sprintf( $text['search'], get_search_query() ), $position );
                echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
            } else {
                if ( $show_current ) {
                    if ( $position >= 1 ) echo $sep;
                    echo $before . sprintf( $text['search'], get_search_query() ) . $after;
                } elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
            }

        } elseif ( is_year() ) {
            if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
            if ( $show_current ) echo $before . get_the_time('Y') . $after;
            elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

        } elseif ( is_month() ) {
            if ( $show_home_link ) echo $sep;
            $position += 1;
            echo sprintf( $link, get_year_link( get_the_time('Y') ), get_the_time('Y'), $position );
            if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('F') . $after;
            elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

        } elseif ( is_day() ) {
            if ( $show_home_link ) echo $sep;
            $position += 1;
            echo sprintf( $link, get_year_link( get_the_time('Y') ), get_the_time('Y'), $position ) . $sep;
            $position += 1;
            echo sprintf( $link, get_month_link( get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m') ), get_the_time('F'), $position );
            if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_time('d') . $after;
            elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

        } elseif ( is_single() && ! is_attachment() ) {
            if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
                $position += 1;
                $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
                if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
                echo sprintf( $link, get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type->name ), $post_type->labels->name, $position );
                if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
                elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
            } else {
                $cat = get_the_category(); $catID = $cat[0]->cat_ID;
                $parents = get_ancestors( $catID, 'category' );
                $parents = array_reverse( $parents );
                $parents[] = $catID;
                foreach ( $parents as $cat ) {
                    $position += 1;
                    if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
                    echo sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
                }
                if ( get_query_var( 'cpage' ) ) {
                    $position += 1;
                    echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_permalink(), get_the_title(), $position );
                    echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['cpage'], get_query_var( 'cpage' ) ) . $after;
                } else {
                    if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
                    elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
                }
            }

        } elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
            $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type() );
            if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                $position += 1;
                if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
                echo sprintf( $link, get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type->name ), $post_type->label, $position );
                echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
            } else {
                if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
                if ( $show_current ) echo $before . $post_type->label . $after;
                elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
            }

        } elseif ( is_attachment() ) {
            $parent = get_post( $parent_id );
            $cat = get_the_category( $parent->ID ); $catID = $cat[0]->cat_ID;
            $parents = get_ancestors( $catID, 'category' );
            $parents = array_reverse( $parents );
            $parents[] = $catID;
            foreach ( $parents as $cat ) {
                $position += 1;
                if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
                echo sprintf( $link, get_category_link( $cat ), get_cat_name( $cat ), $position );
            }
            $position += 1;
            echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_permalink( $parent ), $parent->post_title, $position );
            if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
            elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

        } elseif ( is_page() && ! $parent_id ) {
            if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
            if ( $show_current ) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
            elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

        } elseif ( is_page() && $parent_id ) {
          $parents = get_post_ancestors( get_the_ID() );
          // Получаем ID главной страницы.
          $home_page_ID = get_option( 'page_on_front' );

          foreach ( array_reverse( $parents ) as $pageID ) {
            // И добавляем нашу строку, где проверяем, если ID родительской страницы == ID домашней страницы, то мы просто переходим к следующей итерации цикла.
            if ( $home_page_ID == $pageID ) continue;
            $position += 1;
            if ( $position > 1 ) echo $sep;
            echo sprintf( $link, get_page_link( $pageID ), get_the_title( $pageID ), $position );

          }
          if ( $show_current ) echo $sep . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
          elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

        } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
            if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                $position += 1;
                $tagID = get_query_var( 'tag_id' );
                echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_tag_link( $tagID ), single_tag_title( '', false ), $position );
                echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
            } else {
                if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
                if ( $show_current ) echo $before . sprintf( $text['tag'], single_tag_title( '', false ) ) . $after;
                elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
            }

        } elseif ( is_author() ) {
            $author = get_userdata( get_query_var( 'author' ) );
            if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
                $position += 1;
                echo $sep . sprintf( $link, get_author_posts_url( $author->ID ), sprintf( $text['author'], $author->display_name ), $position );
                echo $sep . $before . sprintf( $text['page'], get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) . $after;
            } else {
                if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
                if ( $show_current ) echo $before . sprintf( $text['author'], $author->display_name ) . $after;
                elseif ( $show_home_link && $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;
            }

        } elseif ( is_404() ) {
            if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
            if ( $show_current ) echo $before . $text['404'] . $after;
            elseif ( $show_last_sep ) echo $sep;

        } elseif ( has_post_format() && ! is_singular() ) {
            if ( $show_home_link && $show_current ) echo $sep;
            echo get_post_format_string( get_post_format() );
        }

        echo $wrap_after;

    }
} // end of dimox_breadcrumbs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось правильно сделать иерархию и заработало.